# First L'Hospital Rule's proof (Bartle 4th ed)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

On the page 183, [image: the page 183] case (a) for example, how can we choose/construct such $c\in (a,b)$ and this $c$ is larger than or equal to $\beta.$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L,
$$
i.e.
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \colon \left(a <x < a+\delta \implies L-\varepsilon < \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)} < L+\varepsilon \right). 
$$
If this $\delta$ is large enough, your $c = a+\delta$ could be bigger than $\beta$. Although we do not require $c > \beta$.

#### UPDATE

$\alpha, \beta$ are arbitrary. In fact the proof could also be written as the following.

> If $L \in \mathbb R$, then given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $$u \in (a,c) \implies L-\varepsilon < \frac {f'(u)}{g'(u)} < L+\varepsilon. $$ Now for $a < \alpha < \beta \leqslant c$, by the Cauchy MVT we have $(2)$. Hence we have $(3)$.

Comment: I also guess that we can choose $c=a+\delta$ but I cant understand why $\beta\leq c.$

Comment: So, On inequality (3), is there a problem if we write $a<\alpha\leq c$? (without mentioning $\beta$)

Comment: $\beta$ is not involved in the choice of $c$.

Comment: We only consider the $\lim _{x \to a^+}$, so actually we could always choose $\beta < c$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't construct $c$ such that $c \geq \beta$. You find $c$ as in previous step. And then assert that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy the inequalities $a<\alpha <\beta \leq c$ then $L-\epsilon <\frac {f(\beta)-f(\alpha)} {g(\beta)-g(\alpha)} <L+\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, my question is how to find such $c$ in "previous step"

Comment: @LocomotiveBangla That is by  definition of limit. It is given that $ \lim _{x \to a+} \frac {f'(x)} {g'(x)} =L$.